# How to Match the string from collection after lookup with many collection using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Here My query**

```
  model.db.aggregate([{$lookup: {from: 'orders', localField: 'prod_id', 
  foreignField: '_id', as: 'Col'}},{$match:{$text: 
  {$search:'Sale'}}}).exec((err,data) => {console.log(data);}]);
```

**but error showing "$match with $text is only allowed as the first pipeline !!"**

I just want to lookup many collection then only I have to  match'Search' in all the data what we joined(lookup) before.
**mongoDb version: 4.0**

Anybody have an idea ? need Help !

Thanks !!

**These all are my Example collections:**

```
    collection 1   ->  
   organization ={'_id':ObjectId("5b110a7b84a0442030a1e9cf"),'Org_name':'dhoni institute','Estd':'1945'}


    collection 2   ->  players= {'_id':ObjectId("45110a7b84a3542030a1e9cf"),'_name':'Ms dhoni','Org_id' = ObjectId("5b110a7b84a0442030a1e9cf") }
```

I am searching the text string 'dhoni' in Db..then I want  all  the documents which contains word 'dhoni' from these collections.

How to do ?

```
   db.players.aggregate([{$match:{$text:{$search:'dhoni'}}},
   {
$lookup{from:'organization',localField:'_id',foreignField:'Org_id',as:'org'}
   }
   ]).exec((err,data) => {}
```

this is my code It only matches the string from 'players' collection .I need matched 'players' collection documents as well as  'Organization' collection documents.

I cannot create new collection because after loopup data may be a huge data so 
I cannot inserting new large data every time search

How to match the string after lookup ?

Comment: try `$mergeObjects` method , please see docs for version above 3.6 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: oops !! I my mongodb version is 3.4 @Robus

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [official mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text),

> $text performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index.

But indexes are reachable only by the first stage of an aggregation query. That's the reason of your error message.

The only way i see for you to use $text/$search is to perform your aggregation (without match stage), adding an $out stage to output to a new collection, create a text index on that collection, and perform your find query with $text/$search criteria.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, but could you provide samples of your collections before?

Comment: I just updated the collections details and my code ! I need your help @matthPen